# How to check if deployments are running on JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Today our Software-Architect gave me the task to implement an "AliveCheck". This means I'll have a war file, which checks if all deployments on our JBoss are running.

Is there a common practice how to implement something like that? I am completely at a loss here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start at the official [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e24215/jboss.htm#GSSOA11126) documentation, chapter 35 " Discovering and Monitoring JBoss Application Server".

But beyond that, you have to understand: it is pretty *hard* to decide from the outside if an application is truly **alive**.

You see, you can have situations where all your threads make progress, and all CPUs are on a constant load - and still the **customer facing** part of the service isn't moving any more.

In other words: your first question should go back to your architect and ask him about the *core* properties of each of your applications.

Meaning: in order to be really **accurate** you need insight into *each* of the applications. Each application must be *architected* in a way that allows for an external service to determine "service X is still alive and doing something useful". This question can't be answered in general - each service might have *different* properties that need observation!

Beyond the first link, another good read regarding this topic: "Release it" by Michael Nygard. Although that book is out for almost 10 years, it nicely discusses the aspect of "insight" into services.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answer. I think I have a lot talking to do with my architect ;) .